# Sum of a function involving logarithm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

**Question**

If $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log x^n}{(\log x)^n} = 4,$$ then what is the value of $x$?

**My working**

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log x^n}{(\log x)^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\log x}{(\log x)^n}$$

Now , let $$a = \log x$$ and we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{na}{a^n} = 4,$$ but I am stuck here. Am I correct so far? If so, what should I do next?

Any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

Following a hint from the comments, I realise that this is an arithmetico-geometric series and the formula for the sum to infinity is given by $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} [a + (n - 1)d]br^{n - 1} = \frac {ab} {1 - r} + \frac {bdr} {(1 - r)^2},$$ where $a$ and $d$ are the first term and common difference of the arithmetic progression respectively while $b$ and $r$ are the first term and common ratio of the geometric progression respectively.

In this case, we have an arithmetic progression with first term $a$ and common difference $a$. We also have a geometric series with first term $a$ and common ratio $a$, so that
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{na}{a^n} & = \frac {a^2} {1 - a} + \frac {a^3} {(1 - a)^2}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac {a^2} {(1 - a)^3}\\[2 mm]
& = 4\\[2 mm]
\implies 4a^3 + 11a^2 - 12a + 4 & = 0\\[ 2mm]
\implies a & = \log x\\[2 mm]
& \approx 0.568\\[2 mm]
\implies x & \approx e^{0.568}
\end{aligned}$$

As I have never encountered such a sequence before, I am wondering whether I have understood the concept correctly and whether my answer is correct!

**Edit 2**

Following another comment, I now believe that we have an arithmetic progression with first term 1 and common difference 1. We also have a geometric series with first term 1 and common ratio $a$, so that
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{na}{a^n} & = \frac 1 {1 - a} + \frac a {(1 - a)^2}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac 1 {(1 - a)^2}\\[2 mm]
& = 4\\[2 mm]
\implies a & = \frac 1 2\\[2 mm]
& = \log x \\[2 mm]
\implies x & = e^{\frac 1 2}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence

Comment: @Blitzer Thank you for the hint! I have worked through the question further and edited my post, but am not sure whether my answer is correct. Would you mind helping me take a look?

Comment: You seem to have miscalculated. Your series is $1+2/a+3/a^2+\cdots=(1-1/a)^{ -2}$.

Comment: @J.G. Hello! I have two queries. Firstly, why couldn't we take the series to be $a/a + 2a/a^2 + 3a/a^3 + \dots$? Isn't the numerator still an AP and the denominator a GP? Secondly, I tried to follow your method but got $(1 - a)^{-2}$ instead (see Edit 2). Would you be able to help me with both queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a well-formatted comment.

This question has encountered some confusion on how to apply various techniques to evaluate $\sum_{n\ge1}na^{1-n}$, so let's go through them.

### Arithmetico-geometric series

We have$$\sum_{n\ge1}[A+(n-1)D]r^{n-1}=\frac{A}{1-r}+\frac{Dr}{(1-r)^2}.$$This problem is the special case $A=D=1,\,r=1/a$.

You seem to have mistakenly taken either $A=a^2,\,D=a^3,\,r=a$ or $A=-a,\,D=a,\,r=1/a$. Or, more realistically, you had an off-by-one error with the indices.

### **Generalized binomial theorem**

I noted $\sum_{n\ge1}na^{1-n}=(1-1/a)^{-2}$, because$$(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1)x^k=\sum_{n\ge1}nx^{n-1}.$$You seem to have confused $a$ with $1/a$, which may also have been an issue with the other method.

You should be able to see either method reduces the problem to $(1-1/a)^{-2}=4$, which I leave you to solve.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am pretty much able to understand the whole thing now, except for the generalised binomial theorem method. In the expansion of $(1 - x)^{-2}$, I believe the terms have alternating signs, starting with positive, so don't we need an extra $(-1)^{n - 1}$ term inside the sum? In particular, shouldn't $(1 - x)^{-2} = \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{n - 1}nx^{n - 1}$?

Comment: @Meng You're thinking of $(1+x)^{-2}$.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you for your help!